# Знак, знать — этимология

Tags: этимология

Существуют ли в старославянском/русском еще существительные, образованные путём присоединения к глагольной основе этимологического ?суффикса? "к", по аналогии с:
 знать -> зна + "к" -> знак;
черпать -> черпа + "к" -> черпак;
(про)вожать -> вожа + "к" -> вожак?

Comment: А Вы не хотите принять хотя бы один ответ на десятки заданных Вами вопросов? Или ни один ответ Вы не считаете верным? Честно говоря, не хочется отвечать: всё равно ответ не будет принят, зачем тратить своё  время? Так Вам скоро никто отвечать не будет.

Answer (score 4):

Возможно, это слово [**брак**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA) (в значении *семейный союз двух (или более) супругов; супружеские отношения*).

Стоит отметить, что слово имеет спорную "морфемную точку зрения" у лингвистов:
корень **-брак-** (Тихонов); корень: **-бр-**, суффиксы **-а-к** (Кузнецова, Ефремова).

Из ст.-слав. *бракъ* — «женитьба», образованного с помощью суффикса -к (как, например, слово «знак») от глагола «брати» — «брать».

**Дополнение**

1. *К ответу @Аллазара*:
   дурак — корень **-дур-**, суффикс **-ак**; кулак (в двух смыслах) — корень **-кулак-**.
   В этих примерах суффикса **-к** нет.
   Со словом **вр/а/к/и** согласна.
2. *К изменениям в вопросе*:
   черпак — корень **-черп-**, суффикс **-ак**; вожак — корень **-вож-**, суффикс **-ак**.
   В этих словах суффикса **-к** тоже нет.

Ещё одно словечко нашлось: драть (драться) — **др/а/к/а**.
Проверить все слова можно в [морфемном словаре](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BA).

Answer (score 1):

Врать — враки (выдуманные истории). Дурить - Дурак. Кулак - раскулачить... Вообщем, примеров достаточно много.